# Trigger a TravisCI build stage conditionally?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am using [TravisCI's Build Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/deploy-npm/) to separate my job to two stages:

1. Build and test on multiple environments.
2. Build and deploy if stage 1 pass.

And I want to Travis to run the jobs on commits to two GitHub branches, `master` and `dev`, and pull requests to `master` and `dev`. However, I only want to run the stage two when a commit to `master` happens.

Is there a way to completely ignore stage 2 in commits to branches that are not `master`, and on pull requests?

This is what my `.travis.yml` looks like at the time of writing this:
https://github.com/SammyIsra/photostream-react/blob/c354a62c3cc963b345a5c2fb95658c90ddc39d21/.travis.yml

*Update:*
this seems to not be possible as of yet. However, the TravisCI team may be working on something like that, as of [this comment on the Build Stages feedback board](https://github.com/travis-ci/beta-features/issues/11#issuecomment-304086106). Whenever I learn that it was added as a feature, or that it will definitely not be possible ever, I will change this question.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to ignore specific branches when triggering jobs in the [build stages section](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages), however it looks like there's a way to only fire your deployments on pushes to `master`.

In your build stage `script` section, you could wrap the `npm run build` command in a quick Bash `if` statement to test the [environment variable which shows what branch you're on](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/):

```
if [ TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then npm run build; fi
```

Then, in your Surge deploy section, you can [restrict the deployment to a particular branch](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/surge/) with:

```
deploy:
    ...
    on: master
```

And basically the same for the [NPM deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/):

```
deploy:
    ...
    on:
        branch: master
```

**Note:** I've not tried any of this myself, so it may or may not work in combination with the new build stages functionality.